# Как сделать, чтобы фокусировка с айтема ListView не исчезала?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Привет всем. Нужно сделать так, чтобы когда `$user_name$` кликал по всему приложению, фокусировка оставалась на выбранном айтеме не изменной, т.е. не проходила и не исчезала. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
  </Trigger>
```

---

Решение найдено.